# What framework does Sagemaker use to train a model?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Models trained on Sagemaker produced `model.tar.gz` files as output.
I want to use these files for prediction on my local machine.

I'm not sure which framework is being used by Sgaemaker to train these models.

I guess I'd have to use the same framework to load the model artifacts for prediction.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the algorithm used

SageMaker supports several built-in algorithms, such as KNN or XGBoost, but you can also bring any algorithm as well, so there's no way for us to know

Opening the .tar.gz file might give some clues as to which algo was used, however...

Comment: Hey I tried opening the model.tar.gz file, but it was just hex values. I was wondering how to load the XGBoost/ KNN algorithms in my local machine.

Comment: XGBoost's model.tar.gz has a  single binary file. KNN has 3 files(algo, labels and json) but it doesn't mention the framework anywhere.